# How to build my xtext language with gradle for android

Tags: intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, xtext, xtext-gradle-plugin

I've written a test-DSL in xtext and generated an IntelliJ plugin.
I have a small Android-test project and in Android Studio my DSL-editor shows up and also generates the output files as expected.

Now I try to configure gradle to also generate the files, but this fails with an error.

I found the *Android Integration* section for the [xtext-builder](http://xtext.github.io/xtext-gradle-plugin/xtext-builder.html). This seems out-dated (e.g. it refers to `org.xtext.android`, which does not exist - also the link there is broken).

Anyway, in the [xtext-gradle-plugin github repo](https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin) there is an `org.xtext.android.builder` plugin: I guess this is the correct one.

My **project `build.gradle`** file looks like this (relevant parts only):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" // needed for org.xtext:xtext-android-gradle-plugin
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath "org.xtext:xtext-android-gradle-plugin:1.0.14"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal() // This is required so that the mydsl language is found
    }
}
```

when I activate the `org.xtext.android.builder` plugin in the **`build.gradle`** file of in my **app module**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "org.xtext.android.builder" // causes the Error!
```

I get this **error**:

```
Error:Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getJavaCompiler()Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/compile/AbstractCompile;'...
```

I guess there's some version mismatch or something is not up-to-date.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug (#73)](https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin/issues/73) in the [xtext-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin). It was fixed in [Version 1.0.16](https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin/releases/tag/1.0.16).